# Core Plot - adding a vertical/horizontal line indicator on a selected value point

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-plot

I am using core plot to make a line graph for my iPhone app. So far I successfully made the line graph from my xml data.

Furthermore I added a text layer that shows the value (for example 40) once I select the cell
holding the value 40. For this, I use the function:

```
(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

So now I want to have a vertical line on the graph to indicate the selected value (the 40). I tried adding CPTBarplot but somehow the bars show only at the beginning of the graph axis.
Is there a function from core plot like the above that will create a line indicator?

I would appreciate if someone can give me some hint how to solve this problem and thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a scatter plot for that. There's a point selection demo in the Mac CPTTestApp that draws a crosshair over the selected point. It would be trivial to modify that to only draw the vertical line.

The `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:` datasource method returns the number of points in the selection indicator (5 for the crosshairs) or zero (0) if there is no current selection. The `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` method returns the points in the indicator. The points are drawn in this order:

1. Left
2. Right
3. Center (with plot symbol)
4. Top
5. Bottom

The `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` method controls the plot symbol in the center. You can eliminate this method if you don't need any symbols on the indicator plot.

Comment: Thank you very much, I made it thanks to your hint and the demo!

Comment: Can you please add a bit of a detail, where in code does this happen? Regards